# GPOTool - Windows 2008R2

Tags: group-policy

I am trying to troubleshoot some GPO issues and began using `gpotool.exe` to diagnose the issue.  I got the tool from 2003 resource kit.  Here is one of the first errors I am seeing:

```
Policy {00FB7F42-7700-4ADE-9714-9B6B69E321D6}  
Friendly name: PC Customizations  
Error: DOM-S02.domain.local - DOM-D01.domain.loca sysvol mismatch
```

I've connected to each system with GPMC and verified that the sysvol versions are the same.  I stumbled across this [link](http://setspn.blogspot.com/2012/06/gpotool-sysvol-mismatch.html) which states there is a newer version due to the false positives of the older version for 2008 R2.  Unfortunately the link to the download is no longer available.  Has anyone seen this? Recommend any other options?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I navigated to the `\\DOM-S01\sysvol\` & `\\DOM-D01\sysvol\` folder and checked the version number for each policy under `gpt.ini` and the numbers were the exact same.  Any other ideas?  I can't find anything else online at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a problem twice, but I forget the exact error text, so this may or may not be your issue.

There was a "support.microsoft.com" article for the problem I had, but I cannot find it at the moment.

The version number of each GPO is stored in both Active Directory and the Filesystem/sysvol. You may have a GPO where the number has gotten out of sync between those two places. Make an educated guess about which side is wrong, and change the number on the wrong side to match the other side so they both match.

**Example**

```
ADSI Edit
CN={02291FC1-60BE-4E1C-A396-6709F7F3E65A},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=youdomain,DC=com
Version=2228230

\\youdomain\sysvol\yourdomain.com\Policies\{02291FC1-60BE-4E1C-A396-6709F7F3E65A}
GPT.ini
[General]
Version=2228230
```

Version = [user version number top 16 bits] [computer version number lower 16 bits]

More details here
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730972.aspx

Comment: The version number in ADSIEDIT is the same as the version number for each of the numbers in the sysvol folder.  ADSIEDIT should represent AD Directory Services and the sysvol folders with the same versions numbers should rule out replication problems??

Comment: No, not necessarily. Are there DFSR errors on either DC? Use a tool like Winmerge to compare the filesystem contents for that GPO. Does it report any differences?

Comment: I am not seeing any DFSR errors on either DC at this point.

Comment: There is a thread on the public MS forums about how the "Version" number is manipulated for GPO's that use WMI filters. Seems as if older tools like 2003 GPOTool have issues on GPO with WMI filters, which were a later enhancement to GPO's. There is a hotfix for the newer OS's to fix this issue in tools like GPResult. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2866345

Answer (score 0):

GPOtool for Windows Server 2008 you can download this link https://www.nibonnet.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/GPOTOOL.zip

It is taken here (French site) https://www.nibonnet.fr/gpotool/